# Antlr (lexer): matching the right token

Tags: antlr, lexer, token, ambiguous

In my Antlr3 grammar, I have several "overlapping" lexer rules, like this:

```
NAT: ('0' .. '9')+ ;
INT: ('+' | '-')? ('0' .. '9')+ ;
BITVECTOR: ('0' | '1')* ;
```

Although tokens like **100110** and **123** can be matched by more than one of those rules, it is always determined by context which of them it has to be. Example:

```
s: a | b | c ;
a: '<' NAT '>' ;
b: '{' INT '}' ;
c: '[' BITVECTOR ']' ;
```

The input **{17}** should then match **{**, **INT**, and **}**, but the lexer has already decided that **17** is a NAT-token. How can I prevent this behavior? The *backtrack* option is already set to true, but it only seems to affect parser rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a complex way to make the lexer context-sensitive, but in general that's what you want the parser to take care of, and you want your lexer to just provide a stream of tokens.  My recommendation is to refactor your lexer to return `DIGITS` and `SIGN` and let your parser work out what kind of number the digits represent by the context.

Comment: Couldn't agree more: leave this up to the parser. +1